# Connect to a DB using DBplyr

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

#### Problem

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server which is on premises using dbplyr using the [instructions here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/schema/) but I keep getting an error saying

> Invalid object name

For simplicity I am using the same object naming convention as RStudio has in the instructions at the link above.

#### Code that produces the error

I use dbConnect to establish a connection:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};server=DO1COMMONSQL01\\COMMON1D;database=datawarehouse;trusted_connection=Yes",
             timeout = 10)
```

I know has been successful because I can see the DB and it's tables in the connections tab.

Then I go to call a simple pipe using `dbplyr`:

```
tbl(con, 'mtcars') %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
```

This is the point at which I get the error message:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'mtcars'.

I have tried other variations on the theme such as `tbl(con, 'dbo.mtcars')...` or `tbl(con, 'datawarehouse.dbo.mtcars'...)` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have linked to, `mtcars` is a table in `datawarehouse`. I am going to assume `mtcars` is in the database you are connecting to. But you can check for this using:

```r
'mtcars' %in% DBI::dbListTables(con)
```

If you want to query a table in a specific database or schema (not the default) then you need to use `in_schema`.

Without `in_schema`:

```r
tbl(con, 'dbo.mtcars')
```

Produces an sql query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "dbo.mtcars"
```

Where the `"` delimit names. So in this case SQL is looking for a table named `dbo.mtcars` not a table named `mtcars` in `dbo`.

With `in_schema`:

```r
tbl(con, in_schema('dbo','mtcars'))
```

Produces an sql query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "dbo"."mtcars"
```

So in this case SQL is looking for a table named `mtcars` in `dbo`. Because each term is `"` quoted separately.